# how can i format date or double values when persisting objects using simple xml

Tags: java, android

I am using simple xml framework from http://simple.sourceforge.net/. How can i format the date or double values? I see a function called transform but how do I apply it all double and date fields in my class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways I can think of to do this.

First:

You can implement your own [`Matcher`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Matcher.html). You can pass this in to the [`Persister`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/core/Persister.html) when you create it. Your `Matcher` only has to return a `Transform` for the types you are interested in. Any type your custom `Matcher` does not match is attempted by the default ones. You'll probably have to take a look at the source code and see how the `DateTransform` and `FloatTransform` are implemented. They are quite short so it's perfectly doable. This solution will be useful only if you want to transform all types in a specific way.

Second:

Create a `String` element that will hold the serialized data.

```
@Element(name = "myelement")
private String strMyElement;

private MyElementType myElement;
```

Then use the @Persist and @Validate annotations to hook into the serialization process.

```
@Persist
private void persist() {
  strMyElement = myElement.toString();
}

@Validate
private void validate() {
  myElement = myElement.fromString(strMyElement);
}
```

This way is a bit more of a hack but it's useful when you only need to override the default serialization in specific cases. It would probably get unwieldy if you had to do it for every instance of a specific type. In that case I'd use the first method.

Comment: Thanks Qberticus. Good suggestions - will try it and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Simple uses a TransformCache to map types to Transformer objects. So if filed is of a `java.lang.Date' type it will use the`org.simpleframework.xml.transform.DateTransform` to transform the Date object to String.

I guess you have to implement a custom Transformer for Date or the primitive long and (temporarily) replace the default Transformer for that type in the cache.

I didn't find any guide too, the drafted strategy is based on a [look on the simple sources](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/report/cobertura/).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I was looking at exactly the same but all the classes are package level and hence i can't extend and replace only the 2 transform methods i require :(... Copying all the classes for my custom matcher doesn't look a good way.